# Creating Events on behalf of a Group using the Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been Googling for an answer for several days now, but most of the solution to similar questions seem to use the deprecated REST-API.

I'm trying to create an event on behalf of a group where I'm the owner, using the Facebook Graph API in PHP.  I can publish an event to my own wall and even to a page using a page specific access-token, but since the group doesn't have any access-token I'm using this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{$group_id}/events?" . {$user_access_token};
```

But something is going wrong and the event gets published only with me as the Owner. My permissions are: "stream_publish, user_groups, create_event, manage_pages"

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you found out how to create a group event? I want to create an event in a group, add a picture and invite the group members.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the undocumented:
`page_id={$group_id}`
parameter to your post.

(as well as posting to the groups event stream)